# GtkCellRendererText ellipsis causes text to completely dissapear

Tags: c, gtk

I have a `GtkTreeView` hooked into a `GtkListStore`, but the `GtkCellRendererText` that's all on it's own in a column, a column which is set to expand.

However the renderer is occupying a max width of 3 characters, just enough for the ellipsis...

While, and after editing the text:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you create your window with GtkBuilder? It might be [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=590020) rearing its ugly head again...

Comment: It does seem to be the problem I'm looking at, don't suppose you know which version of gtk+ I can use to negate this?

Comment: I don't think it's been fixed yet.

Comment: So basically I have to stick the entire table in a frame and remove ellipsing or else?

Comment: How about leaving the ellipsis value out and then adding it in at runtime, that would negate me having to rebuild the gui and only add one line to the program. I tried `g_object_set_data` but that evidently isn't what gtk wants (`GtkCellRendererText` doesn't have a method for changing it's inconsistent state)

Comment: No, I had to write the whole treeview manually. Pity. Oh well, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `max-width-chars` property on the cell renderer.

Comment: This is all well and good unless I want it to expand, which I do as users can change the size of the window